# Problems with an ActiveRecord join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm having a problem solving a Query using ActiveRecord. The query description is: "Return itineraries associated with trips that an agent has created"

This is what i tried:

```
trips = Trip.where("agent_id = ? AND is_itinerary", params[:id])
        .joins('LEFT JOIN itineraries ON trips.id = itineraries.trip_id LEFT JOIN users ON itineraries.user_id = users.id')
         .select('trips.*, itineraries.status, users.*')
```

The results seems to be ok, but a problem is the returning id of the records. They are duplicated and instead of being the Trip.id looks like the returning id is the User.id.

Has someone any idea of how to solve it? Maybe changing the default grouping strategy?

The tables are: Itineraries (id, trip_id, user_id), Trips (id, ...), User (id, ...)

Comment: I think `users.*` is overriding the column `id` from the one that comes in `trips.*`, is there a reason you're loading all the content at once in one query instead of two separate queries with eager loading?

Comment: Mmm, not any particular reason. Are you suggesting to split the query in two parts? The first one must have the itineraries users join part, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem separating the original query:

```
trips = Trip.where("agent_id = ? AND is_itinerary", params[:id]).joins('LEFT JOIN itineraries ON trips.id = itineraries.trip_id').select('trips.*, itineraries.status')
            trips = trips.joins("LEFT JOIN users ON itineraries.user_id = users.id").select("users.*")
```

Doing it in that way Users.* attributes don't override the Trips attributes.